# Installing PiccSIM network control system simulation software on Ubuntu

Tags: networking

I am currently working on my research on security issues associated with Wireless Sensor Network Control Systems. 
Also i have been trying to install PiccSIM on Ubuntu for a few days now but i keep getting the following errors:

```
marolinks@ubuntu:~/Desktop/Ns2/PiccSIM_ns-2.34_bundle$ ./installPiccSIM_1.00_2.34.sh
./installPiccSIM_1.00_2.34.sh: 3: ./installPiccSIM_1.00_2.34.sh: make: not found
./installPiccSIM_1.00_2.34.sh: 5: ./installPiccSIM_1.00_2.34.sh: cp: not found
./installPiccSIM_1.00_2.34.sh: 6: ./installPiccSIM_1.00_2.34.sh: patch: not found
./configure: 4: ./configure: sed: not found
./configure: line 182: sed: command not found
./configure: line 446: expr: command not found
./configure: line 458: sed: command not found
./configure: line 472: sed: command not found
: error: cannot create .lineno; rerun with a POSIX shell
./installPiccSIM_1.00_2.34.sh: 9: ./installPiccSIM_1.00_2.34.sh: make: not found
marolinks@ubuntu:~/Desktop/Ns2/PiccSIM_ns-2.34_bundle$
```

Please can i get any support from you on how to resolve this

Comment: where did you find it? It looks like you are missing dependencies (like "make") or that it is not intended for your system

Comment: It was provided by Aalto University for research relating to Wireless sensor networks. Here's the link http://wsn.aalto.fi/en/tools/piccsim/

Answer (score 0):

> Any Linux version supported by ns-2 and a recent java (openjdk-6-jre) package should work. PiccSIM is
>   tested Ubuntu 8.04 and later. The following packages should be installed (e.g. sudo apt-get install):
>   build-essential, automake, autoconf, diff, gcc, tcl, tar, grep, libpcap0.8,
>   libpcap0.8-dev, libx11-dev, xlibs-dev.

You are missing =at least= "build-essential"

Answer (score 0):

you need to copy the PiccSIM_ns-2.34_bundle to ns-2.34 folder and copy the files in the common folder of PiccSIM_ns-2.34_bundle to the common folder of ns-2.34. Also copy the installPiccSIM_1.00_2.34.sh file to ns-2.34 folder then only you can run the command ./installPiccSIM_1.00_2.34.sh